# Post form - AJAX won't upload featured image - Plugin development

Tags: php, plugin-development, posts, ajax, javascript

I have a form for adding a post via `AJAX` and `PHP`. I have three fields. `Text`, `textarea` and `file` input field.

Everything it's working, but it won't upload a featured image. When I remove the `AJAX` call, then it's working. It only uploads the `text` and the `textarea` field.

Here is the form:

```
public function pp_html_template() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return '<h2>' . __( 'Publish your post', 'post-publisher' ) . '</h2>
        <form id="pp-form-submit" name="pp-form-submit" class="pp-form-submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">' .
       wp_nonce_field( 'pp_publisher_save', 'pp_publisher_name' )
       . '<div class="pp-row">
                <label for="pp_title">' . esc_attr__( 'Title', 'post-publisher' ) . '</label>
                <input type="text" id="pp_title" name="pp_title">
            </div>

            <div class="pp-row">
                <label for="pp_content">' . esc_attr__( 'Content', 'post-publisher' ) . '</label>
                <textarea name="pp_content" id="pp_content" name="pp_content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            
            <div class="pp-row">
                <label for="pp_featured_image">' . esc_attr__( 'Featured Image', 'post-publisher' ) . '</label>
                <input type="file" id="pp_featured_image" name="pp_featured_image">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="pp_html_process"/>
            <div class="pp-row">
                <input type="submit" name="pp_submit" id="pp_submit">
            </div>
        </form>';
    }
}
```

Here is the form process:

```
public function pp_html_process() {

    // Process the form
    if ( isset( $_POST['pp_submit'] ) ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['pp_publisher_name'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['pp_publisher_name'], 'pp_publisher_save' ) ) {
            esc_attr__( 'Sorry, this action is not allowed.', 'post-publisher' );
            exit;
        } else {
            global $current_user;

            $user_login   = $current_user->user_login;
            $user_id      = $current_user->ID;
            $post_title   = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pp_title'] );
            $post_content = sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['pp_content'] );

            $new_post = array(
                'post_title'   => $post_title,
                'post_content' => $post_content,
                'post_type'    => 'post',
                'post_status'  => 'draft',
                'post_name'    => str_replace( ' ', '-', $post_title ),
            );

            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post, true );

            if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata' ) ) {
                require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php' );
                require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php' );
                require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php' );
            }


            $featured_image = media_handle_upload( 'pp_featured_image', $post_id );
            if ( $featured_image > 0 ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $featured_image );
            }

            if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
                echo 'Post created! ID';
                wp_die();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `__contstruct()`

```
public function __construct() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        add_shortcode( 'pp_html_template', array( $this, 'pp_html_template' ) );
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'pp_html_process' ) );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_pp_html_process', array( $this, 'pp_html_process' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pp_html_process', array( $this, 'pp_html_process' ) );

}
```

And here is the AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function ajaxSubmit() {
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        formData.append('pp_submit', 1);

        $.ajax({
            action: 'pp_featured_image',
            type: 'POST',
            url: public_ajax.ajaxurl,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('success', response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log('error!', response);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

    $('#pp-form-submit').submit(ajaxSubmit);
});
```

I'm not getting any errors in the console. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `if ( is_wp_error( $featured_image ) ) { wp_die( $featured_image ); }` *right after* you called `media_handle_upload()`. If there was an error, then the dump output would show it. (Just check the console to see the dump output)

Comment: @SallyCJ There are no errors. It is just loading: https://prnt.sc/1t8wkqs 

The featured image is working just fine without AJAX.

Comment: Sorry about that "dump output" - I forgot to edit that part in my comment. Anyway, try uploading a new PNG/JPEG image, via your form, and see if the image is in the Media → Library? Also, [try enabling `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Comment: You can also try using `fetch()` instead - replace the whole `jQuery.ajax()` call with `fetch( public_ajax.ajaxurl, { method: 'POST', body: formData } ).then( res => res.text() ).then( data => console.log( 'fetch success', data ) );` However, judging from that [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/1t8wkqs), the server may have failed to generate the thumbnail's metadata (which includes sub-sizes/resized images) or maybe a plugin/code caused the issue. So try deactivating all plugins and see if the same issue persists.

Comment: Hey @SallyCJ, thanks for your help, but the issue was up to the folder permission. Now everything works.

Comment: Can you post an answer and explain how did you identify the root cause of the issue and what did you do to fix it? I'm sure it would be beneficial to others including myself. (And remember to accept your answer later)

Comment: Also, despite the issue has been resolved, I suggest you to check whether `wp_insert_post()` or `media_handle_upload()` returned a `WP_Error` before proceeding to the next action. (see my very 1st comment for an example)